Refused to connect. /sign-oidc
In my .NET Blazor application, the after successful authentication using Azure B2C (Azure sign-in log shows 'Success'), the error page is returned with the URL https://localhost: /signin-oidc
Error #1
Error #2
Unfortunately, there are no logs to illuminate the cause of the error.
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
{
    options.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    builder.Configuration.Bind("OpenIDConnect", options);

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async ctxt =>
        {
            logger.Info($"On Redirect To Identity Provider : {ctxt.Request.Host.Value}");
            await Task.Yield();
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = async ctxt =>
        {
            logger.Info($"On Authentication Failed");
            Console.WriteLine("On Authentication Failed");
            await Task.Yield();
        },
        OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = async ctxt =>
        {
            logger.Info($"On Signed Out Callback Redirect");

            ctxt.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(ctxt.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri);
            ctxt.HandleResponse();
            await Task.Yield();
        },
        OnMessageReceived = async ctxt =>
        {
            logger.Info($"On Message Received : {ctxt.Request.Path.Value}");
        },
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
        {
            logger.Info("Authorization Code Received");

            Console.WriteLine("Authorization Code Received");
        },
        OnTokenValidated = async context =>
        {
            logger.Info("Token Validated");

            Console.WriteLine("Token Validated");
        },
        OnRemoteFailure = async ctxt =>
        {
            logger.Info($"On Remote Failure : {ctxt.Failure?.Message}");
            ctxt.Response.Redirect("/");
            ctxt.HandleResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("On Remote Failure");

        },
        OnTokenResponseReceived = async ctxt =>
        {
            logger.Info($"On Access Denied");

            Console.WriteLine("OnTokenResponseReceived");
        },
        OnTicketReceived = async ctxt =>
        {
            logger.Info($"On Ticket Received : {ctxt.Request.Path.Value}");
         }
        );

The log records OnRedirectToIdentityProvider event, but there is no logs on OnRemoteFailure or OnTokenResponseReceived.
Could you please advise me on how to resolve this error or log it for reference?
Thanks in advance. Any help appreciated.

Please provide the error in text format.

Please specify whether you're using Blazor Server or Blazor WebAssembly (WASM), as well as the .NET version you’re working with.

Temporarily remove or comment out the options.Events configuration and test if the problem persists.services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)     .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID- xxxxxxxxx
Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.
Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application. Check the server logs for error details and enable logging.

@AsleshaKantamsetti I am using Blazor server .NET 8.

I have already tried removing options.Events configuration still does not work. It fails at OnRemoteFailure, i get Correlation Failed error in the logs. @AsleshaKantamsetti

Check that your launchSettings.json file is set like this: ```environmentVariables": {
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
}


Share your appsettings.json file without secrets.

"IIS Express": {
"commandName": "IISExpress",
"launchBrowser": true,
"environmentVariables": {
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
}

"AllowedHosts": "*",
"AzureAdB2C": {
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
"ClientId": "xxx",
"ClientSecret": "xxx",
"Domain": "xxx",
"Instance": "xxx",
"ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_passwordreset",
"SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_Signupsignin",
"SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_Signupsignin",
"TenantId": "xxx",
"SkipUnrecognizedRequests": true,
"CookieOptions": {
"SecurePolicy": "Always",
"HttpOnly": true,
"IsEssential": true
}
@AsleshaKantamsetti

I created a sample Blazor server (.NET 8) application and successfully authenticated using Azure B2C.
I referred to this blog for creating the application and configuring Azure B2C authentication.
Make sure you're defining correct policy name, domain or instance in your appsettings.json
appsettings.json:
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://{ Azure B2C Domain Name}.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
    "ClientId": "<Client-Id>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Domain": "{ Azure B2C Domain Name}.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_Blazorsigninsingup",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": ""
  },
    "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
  }


Ensure that ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is set to Development in the launchSettings.json file

 "https": {
   "commandName": "Project",
   "dotnetRunMessages": true,
   "launchBrowser": true,
   "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7288;http://localhost:5056",
   "environmentVariables": {
     "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
   }

program.cs:
using blazorb2c.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
using blazorb2c.Components;
namespace BlazorAzureB2C
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        
            builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            
            var env = builder.Environment;
            builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"appsettings{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
            builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), true);
                 builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
                .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
            builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
            builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<HttpContextAccessor>();
                        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
                {
                    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async ctxt =>
                        {
                            await Task.Yield();
                        },
                        OnAuthenticationFailed = async ctxt =>
                        {
                            
                            await Task.Yield();
                        },
                        OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = async ctxt =>
                        {
                            ctxt.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(ctxt.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri);
                            ctxt.HandleResponse();
                            await Task.Yield();
                        },
                        OnTicketReceived = async ctxt =>
                        {
                            if (ctxt.Principal != null)
                            {
                                if (ctxt.Principal.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
                                {
                                    var colClaims = await ctxt.Principal.Claims.ToDynamicListAsync();
                                    var IdentityProvider = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider")?.Value;
                                    var Objectidentifier = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier")?.Value;
                                    var EmailAddress = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress")?.Value;
                                    var FirstName = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname")?.Value;
                                    var LastName = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname")?.Value;
                                    var AzureB2CFlow = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnclassreference")?.Value;
                                    var auth_time = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "auth_time")?.Value;
                                    var DisplayName = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "name")?.Value;
                                    var idp_access_token = colClaims.FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => c.Type == "idp_access_token")?.Value;
                                }
                            }
                            await Task.Yield();
                        },
                    };
                });
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
            var app = builder.Build();
            
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.MapControllers();
            app.UseAntiforgery();
            app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
                .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
            app.Run();
        }
    }
}

Add the correct Redirect URI to your Azure B2C app registration as shown below.

Check if you are using correct User flow name in the appsettings.json.

Now I've successfully authenticated to Azure B2C.
Output:



